# how to fix eclipse frameworkevent errors at launch after migrating from neon to 2019 12

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi-bundle

After upgrading a eclipse neon install to 2019 12, I get the following errors when I launch eclipse:

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core [314]
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui [316]
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.compatibility [341]
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.userstorage [803]
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.userstorage.ui [804]

I am a beginner with eclipse, so please tell me how to proceed to fix these errors.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the same workspace? I would create a new one and import the projects over. Neon to 2019-12 is a very big upgrade...

Comment: Yes I use the same workspace. All errors are related to the "equinox" bundle. Maybe I need to update the equinox bundle, but I don't know how to do it, I am really quite new on eclipse.

Comment: So try creating a new workspace. The way Eclipse works is it adds into the workspace folder all the references (jar files) to the plugins you have installed. So since Neon version a bunch of plugins may have been deprecated and removed, therefore your errors. You will likely miss some plugins or at least will need to install the new version of then

Comment: What you can do, is to go into your workspace folder and there is a folder called `.metadata/.plugins` there you can try to manually delete all jars related to equinox and see what happen... though I would not recommend this because if you miss delete something the problem may even turn worst...

Comment: ok, will try by creating a new workspace and will let you know

Comment: workspace is created and it sounds like eclipse launches with no error. How do I migrate all the projects I had in the other workspace into this new one? oops, just got it with google, so I am importing all projects and relaunch eclipse to see if everything is fine